# I want to sort my MDDatTable by my id how can i do it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

Can somebody help me sort my MDDataTabel by my id?
I don't use my id in the table itself but I get it out of my database
so can I use it to sort it?

```
def build1(self, username):
    screen = Builder.load_string(screen_helper)
    sql = "SELECT LoggedInUser from ID191774_6itn1project7.DetectedObjects where LoggedInUser = %s   "
    mycursor.execute(sql, (username))
    self.User = mycursor.fetchall()
    sql = "SELECT ObjectName from ID191774_6itn1project7.DetectedObjects where LoggedInUser = %s     "
    mycursor.execute(sql, (username))
    self.Object = mycursor.fetchall()
    sql = "SELECT Certainty from ID191774_6itn1project7.DetectedObjects  where LoggedInUser = %s    "
    mycursor.execute(sql, (username))
    self.Certainty = mycursor.fetchall()
    sql = "SELECT TimeOfDetection from ID191774_6itn1project7.DetectedObjects where LoggedInUser = %s     "
    mycursor.execute(sql, (username))
    self.Time = mycursor.fetchall()
    sql = "SELECT  idObjecten from ID191774_6itn1project7.DetectedObjects where LoggedInUser = %s     "
    mycursor.execute(sql, (username))
    self.IDDataTable = mycursor.fetchall()

    self.data_tables = MDDataTable(
        size_hint=(0.9, 0.6),
        use_pagination=True,
        rows_num=10,
        column_data=[
            ("User", dp(30)),
            ("Object", dp(30)),
            ("Certainty", dp(30)),
            ("Time", dp(30)),

        ],
        row_data=[
            (self.User),
            (self.Object),
            (self.Certainty),
            (self.Time),

        ],
    )
    return screen
```

This is my code.
pls help me.